# typescript number getting undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 intervalID: number;
  value: number=0;

startGame(){
    console.log("gameStarted");
    this.intervalID=window.setInterval(this.currentNumber,2000); 
  }

currentNumber(){
    console.log("in current number");
    console.log(this.value);//**Here i am getting undefined**
    this.value++;
    console.log(this.value);// **here i am getting NaN**
    this.numberGenerated.emit({currentValue:this.value});
  }
```

When using value in currentNumber, i am getting undefined. As a result any operations done on value leads to NaN

Comment: I would try ```this.intervalID=window.setInterval(() => { this.currentNumber(); }, 2000);```

Answer (score 2):

Change :

```
 this.intervalID=window.setInterval(this.currentNumber,2000);
```

To:

```
this.intervalID=window.setInterval(() => this.currentNumber(),2000);
```

[As arrow functions preserve `this`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html).